# How do I allow client to access specific folders within a Digital Ocean droplet via FTP?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ftp, digital-ocean, droplet

I have installed a LEMP stack on Ubuntu 16.04, added server blocks for different sites but I would like to be able to allow clients to access their files without having complete access to the server.

I have followed this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04 up to Step 3 - add a new user. As I am not familiar with command line (I get by!) I'm not sure that the rest of the guide's commands is what I want to achieve.

The folder I would like my client to access is located /var/www/client-site

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use these commands

```
sudo chown nobody:nogroup /var/www
sudo chmod a-w /var/www

sudo chown USER:USER /var/www/client-site
```

and then

```
sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

where you then set this

```
local_root=/var/www/
```

This will allow the client to start at /var/www/ and then only have access to there client-site